# Derivation of ∀x (A(x) → B(x)) → (∀x A(x) → ∀x B(x)) in Hilbert style system

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, formal-proofs

While it's quite easy to give a derivation of

$$\forall x ~ \bigg(A(x) \implies B(x)\bigg) \implies \bigg(\forall x~ A(x) \implies \forall x~ B(x)\bigg)$$

in a system that contains the rule of Universal Instantiation, how do you give one in a Hilbert style system like the one in Derek Goldrei's *Predicate and Propositional Calculus: A Model of Argument*. His Axiom 4,

$$\forall x (A \implies A[t/x]) \tag{Axiom 4}$$

where $t$ is free for $A$,  seems to work as a kind of UI, but I'm not that sure. What I'm trying to say is:  Does Axiom 4 warrant the inference:

$$\forall x~ (A(x) \implies B(x))$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$\text{(Apply Axiom 4)}$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$(A(x) \implies B(x))$$

...?

Comment: Is that axiom even sound? Unless I'm misunderstanding something, $\forall x(A\to A[t/x])$ would have one of its instances $\forall x(x=1\to 0=1)$ (taking $t$ to be $0$), but that is not a true statement (because taking $x$ to be $1$ makes $x=1\to0=1$ false).

Comment: Isn't x always freely substitutable for itself ?

Comment: Ax.4 is wrongly written; it must be : $\forall x \phi(x) \to \phi(t/x)$. See Goldrei, page 221.

Comment: @Mauro: That one is sound, but that is exactly what is called "universal instantiation", right? I'm confused because the OP seems to say that the axiom he's talking about is _not_ universal instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

1)$∀x (A(x) \to B(x))$ --- premise [a]

2) $∀x A(x)$ --- premise [b]

3) $A(x) \to B(x)$ --- from 1) by Ax.4 and *modus ponens*

4) $A(x)$ --- from 2) by Ax.4 and *modus ponens*

5) $B(x)$ --- from 3) and 4) by *mp*

6) $∀x B(x)$ --- from 5) by *Gen* rule : $x$ is not free in [a] nor in [b]

> 7) $\vdash  ∀x (A(x) \to B(x)) \to (∀x A(x) \to ∀x B(x))$ --- from 1), 2) and 6) by *Deduction theorem* twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since "Hilbert style system" is mentioned. It would be better if not using deduction theorem. I can reduce to just use it one time.

$\forall x(Ax\to Bx)$----------------------------Hyp

$\forall x(Ax\to Bx)\to(At\to Bt)$-----------Axiom 5

$\forall xAx\to At$------------------------------Axiom 5

$\forall y(\forall xAx\to By)\to(\forall xAx\to \forall yBy)$-Axiom 6

$At\to Bt$---------------------------------1,2 MP

$\forall xAx\to Bt$-----------------------------3,5 HS

$\forall y(\forall xAx\to By)$------------------------6 Gen

$\forall xAx\to \forall yBy$--------------------------4,7 HS

$\forall xAx\to \forall xBx$--------------------------Replace y by x

$\forall x(Ax\to Bx)\vdash\forall xAx\to \forall xBx$

$\vdash\forall x(Ax\to Bx)\to\forall xAx\to \forall xBx\quad$ Use deduction theorem one time.

Comment: Sorry.. it is deduction theorem